# Probability of getting defective vs good bulbs of specific number in given situation

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

> Four defective bulbs are accidentally mixed with 10 good ones. It is not possible to tell from seeing if a bulb is defective or not. Now, 3 bulbs are drawn at random from this lot without replacement. What is the probability that (i) getting 1 defective bulb and (ii) getting 2 defective bulbs?

For this, the total number of ways of drawing is $14 \times 13 \times 12$ as we are drawing 3 bulbs without replacement.

Now, for part (i), to get $1$ defective in a draw of $3$, I can draw the defective one in $4$ ways, and the good ones in $10\times 9$ ways. So the probability of drawing $1$ defective bulb in a draw of 3 amounts to $\frac{15}{91}$ but my book says it to be $\frac{45}{91}$ using $$\frac{{4 \choose 1}{10\choose 2}}{14\choose 3} = \frac{45}{91}$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You did not consider whether the defective bulb is drawn in the first or second or third draw. So for that you need to multiply by 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The total number of ways of drawing is $14 \times 13 \times 12$

Here, you are assuming that the order in which you draw the bulbs is important. In other words, drawing $(A, B, C)$ is different from $(C, B, A)$.

> Now, for part (i), to get $1$ defective in a draw of $3$, I can draw the defective one in $4$ ways, and the good ones in $10 \times 9$ ways.

And I suppose you just took the total number of "successful" ways to be $4 \times 10 \times 9$. But this only accounts for one specific arrangement of the defective bulb among the nondefective ones; i.e., if $A$ is defective and $B, C$ are not, then you have counted only one of $\{(A, B, C), (B, A, C), (B, C, A)\}$ and not the other two, and the same for every combination of defective-nondefective choices. To correct your count, you can multiply the number of "successful" ways by $3$.